# Styling Scrollbars on QTextEdit (Using custom images)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the simple UI below and I want to make customize everything in it. I've managed to use custom Window using a transparent PNG and I also tried making custom buttons with different states and they all work perfectly. Does anyone know how to style the scrollbars on QTextEdit?

I searched around everywhere and I couldn't find anything about QTextEdit scrollbars.

```
#!usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os.path #file check
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui #pyqt stuff
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint #dragable window
from gui.guiMain import Ui_main

class mainUi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.ver = '2.0.0'
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True) #accept file drops
        self.ui = Ui_main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.oldPos = None
        self.setFixedSize(401, 286) #no resize
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) #frameless window
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        self.ui.exitBtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    qproperty-iconSize: 32px 32px;
                    image: url(":/res/icons/close.png");
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/close-hover.png");
                }
                QPushButton:pressed {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/close-focus.png");
                }
            """)
        self.ui.btnBtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    qproperty-iconSize: 32px 32px;
                    image: url(":/res/icons/main.png");
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/main-hover.png");
                }
                QPushButton:pressed {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/main-focus.png");
                }
            """)
        #ui functions
        self.ui.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self._exit)
        self.ui.btnBtn.clicked.connect(self._btnBtn)

        ##########################
        ####### Variables ########
        ##########################
        title = 'Test Window'
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.ui.titleLbl.setText(title)
        self.ui.titleLbl.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: white; font-size:35px; font-family:IranNastaliq;}')
        text = '<p style="text-align:center; color:white;">'
        sher = """12345
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text..."""
        sher = sher.replace('\n', '<br />')
        text += sher
        text += '</p>'
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(text)
        self.ui.textEdit.setStyleSheet("""
            QTextEdit {
                font-size:15px;
                font-family:Vazir FD;
            }
        """)

    ##############################
    ####### Functions ############
    ##############################
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.oldPos:
            delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
            #print(delta)
            self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def _btnBtn(self):
        print('btnBtn')

    def _exit(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(':/res/fonts/Vazir-FD.ttf') #add custom font no install
    QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(':/res/fonts/IranNastaliq.ttf') #add custom font no install
    main = mainUi()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you have to add a scrollbar first then attach it to your QTextEdit using setVerticalScrollBar. Then you can customize the QScrollBar itself. Here is an example. In my UI file, I've added a scrollbar called sbar which gets attached to the textEdit:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os.path #file check
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui #pyqt stuff
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint #dragable window
from gui.guiMain import Ui_main

class mainUi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.ver = '2.0.0'
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True) #accept file drops
        self.ui = Ui_main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.oldPos = None
        self.setFixedSize(401, 286) #no resize
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) #frameless window
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        self.ui.exitBtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    qproperty-iconSize: 32px 32px;
                    image: url(":/res/icons/close.png");
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/close-hover.png");
                }
                QPushButton:pressed {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/close-focus.png");
                }
            """)
        self.ui.btnBtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    qproperty-iconSize: 32px 32px;
                    image: url(":/res/icons/main.png");
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/main-hover.png");
                }
                QPushButton:pressed {
                    image: url(":/res/icons/main-focus.png");
                }
            """)
        #ui functions
        self.ui.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self._exit)
        self.ui.btnBtn.clicked.connect(self._btnBtn)

        ##########################
        ####### Variables ########
        ##########################
        title = 'Test Window'
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.ui.titleLbl.setText(title)
        self.ui.titleLbl.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: white; font-size:35px; font-family:IranNastaliq;}')
        self.ui.sbar.setStyleSheet("""
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background:white;
    width:10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    min-height: 0px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0  rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0 px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
        """)
        self.ui.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBar(self.ui.sbar)
        text = '<p style="text-align:center; color:white;">'
        sher = """12345
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text...
Sample text..."""
        sher = sher.replace('\n', '<br />')
        text += sher
        text += '</p>'
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(text)
        self.ui.textEdit.setStyleSheet("""
            QTextEdit {
                font-size:15px;
                font-family:Vazir FD;
            }
        """)

    ##############################
    ####### Functions ############
    ##############################
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.oldPos:
            delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
            #print(delta)
            self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def _btnBtn(self):
        print('btnBtn')

    def _exit(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(':/res/fonts/Vazir-FD.ttf') #add custom font no install
    QtGui.QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(':/res/fonts/IranNastaliq.ttf') #add custom font no install
    main = mainUi()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```